# Pass by reference (aliasing issue)

Tags: parameter-passing, alias

I am currently learning principles of programming languages. Can anyone tell me what does it mean that pass by reference can lead to aliasing issues?

Comment: Are you familiar with what passing by reference is? Are you familiar with what aliasing issues are?

Comment: I am familiar with pass by ref but im not able to understand the meaning of aliasing issues.

Comment: 'Aliasing' in general refers to ways you're able to reference values and data. So an 'aliasing' issue can be when multiple names inadvertently refer to the same value, or when you lose a way to alias data.

Answer (score 0):

Aliasing occurs when multiple symbols point to to the same memory block.  This should be avoided to reduce confusion.  Below is a trivial example of aliasing:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    int& alias = array[3];  // alias points to 4th element in the array.

    alias = 100;    // 4th element in the array set to 100!
                    // this is best avoided because it is not
                    // immediately obvious that assigning a value
                    // to alias will affect the array.

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); ++i)
        std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

```
Success  time: 0 memory: 3340 signal:0
0
1
2
100
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

In this example it is obvious enough that `alias` points to the 4th element in the array, but in large production environments this can wreak havoc and create difficult to solve bugs.

Comment: well its still not much clear as to how its harmful....maybe there is a small example?

Answer (score -2):

By pass by reference, method can change the original data.